# How much did I make in profit from Bitcoin rising in price

Tags: mining-profitability

I bought $30.00 of Bitcoin. The price at that time was $6,896.00. The price now is $8,074.00. How much did I make?
And how do I do the math?

Comment: "It concerns me that people who lack such basic knowledge of economy would invest in a cryptocurrency."– Myridium

Comment: Crazy how you make a comment like that, as if that is supposed to mean something. This is a new market, something like when Wall Street started. By no means should you judge or underestimate anyone. This is not the platform for that. So with that being said. How about teaching someone something.

Comment: @Badrobot, you clearly posted this naive question in hopes that it would get attention, and you could spam the comments with cloud mining links.  You have been reported.

Comment: Ok didn't mean to offend. Just seen that Bitcoin is back up

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a maths or investment question than a cryptocurrency one.

Comment: Yeah, also, the rule of three seems to be well covered in other parts of the internet… :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not made any money until you have sold your bitcoin. The numbers in the previous answer refer to your unrealised capital gains. Remember that you may have to pay tax on your gains if you do decide to sell and adjust your winnings accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

30 / 6896 * 8074 = 35.1247099767981

So, you've made a net profit of $5.12., which is (5.12 / 30) a profit margin of 17.06 percent.

For a more indepth answers about realized and unrealized profit/loss for investments, and specifically Bitcoin, check [What happens if I buy Bitcoins and the price goes down?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/62896/10658)

Comment: @Badrobot remember to accept this answer if it satisfies your question, don't leave it "unanswered" :)